# Using function returning custom type in multi database environment

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, plsql

I got simple utils package with function which turn delimited string into custom table. It is usefull. The definition is like this:

```
create or replace type StringArray as table of varchar2(60);

create or replace PACKAGE utils
IS
  FUNCTION Explode(p_Seperator IN VARCHAR2,p_String IN VARCHAR2) RETURN Stringarray;
END utils;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY utils
IS
    FUNCTION Explode(p_Seperator IN VARCHAR2,p_String IN VARCHAR2) RETURN Stringarray
    AS
      v_String LONG DEFAULT p_String || p_Seperator;
      v_Data Stringarray := Stringarray();
      n NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      LOOP
      EXIT WHEN v_String IS NULL;
      n := Instr(v_String, p_Seperator);
      v_Data.Extend;
      v_Data(v_Data.Count) := Ltrim(Rtrim(SUBSTR(v_String, 1, n - 1)));
      v_String := SUBSTR(v_String, n + 1);
      END LOOP;
      RETURN v_Data;
    END Explode;
END utils;
```

And use example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as letter FROM table(utils.explode(',','a,b,c,d'))
```

I used it succesfully from some time. Now, I need to use it in many database environment, and here the problems begin.
Lets consider database A with table T and database B with dblink @A to database A. And our task is to update table T in database A from database B. And the keys are comma separated string like this: 'a,b,c,d', so it is convinient to use our utils.explode function. 
To make things easy, lets say  that we can define type and package in both databases.

When I try to use function from database B like this:

```
UPDATE
  T@A 
SET
    field = 'TEST'
WHERE
  key IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM table(utils.explode(',','1,2,3')))
;
```

I get error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-22804:  "remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined type columns"
22804. 00000 -  "remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined type columns"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform queries or DML operations on
       remote object
       tables or on remote table columns whose type is one of object,
       REF, nested table or VARRAY.
```

And when I want to invoke function from database A like this:

```
UPDATE
  T@A 
SET
    field = 'TEST'
WHERE
  key IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM table(utils.explode@A(',','1,2,3')))
;
```

I get error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-30626:"function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported"
30626. 00000 -  "function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This is my problem.

I know that I can create custom procedure in database A and send it keys as string, and inside use explode function and do the update.
Or I can do what Tom suggested [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:6020795600346824518).

But I use this technique in many places, with different tables and different fields. This explode function is clean, simple and all-purpose tool for use.

That is why I am not seeking some one shot solution which involves creating custom objects per use case, but something more universal.

In more abstract way of putting it, my problem is about sending collection (or array or table) of values between databases in plsql.

Can somebody help me with it, please? :)

[Edit]
Nobody can help me with this? Not even comment?

Comment: Re "Edit": I'm still thinking about solving your problem. :-)

Comment: Oh, it is good thing to hear. I was losing hope. :) 
The development is going on, so we produced some workarounds, but they are much less elegant. That is why some solution would be still much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For a while i was hoping this [article](https://blog.dsl-platform.com/query-user-defined-types-over-database-link/) can solve your problem, but unfortunately the only working method (i came with and surely you too) is not so elegant, but at least gets the job done:

```
insert into global_temporary_explode (select column_value as letter from table(utils.explode(',','1,2,3')));
```

and

```
update T@A set field = 'TEST' where key in (select column_value from  global_temporary_explode);
```

Comment: Thank You for Your research, to be honest I did not think about temp table. It is certainly more elegant solution than multiple loops. ;) I tested and upvoted Your answer, because it certainly work as should. But it isn't exactly what I wanted. For example, when I would like to update multiple tables in the same session I need to clear temp table after each one, things get complicated if I would like to use explode in remote query where clause multiple times in one statement and so on... So please understand that I will not accept it as correct one (at least not now ;).